# В чём разница между API token и API id, hash?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, pyrogram

Пытаюсь написать своего телеграм-бота через библиотеку [pyrogram](https://docs.pyrogram.org). Для того чтобы подключиться к боту и управлять им, необходимо предоставить API token, API id и API hash, как показано ниже (пример взят [отсюда](https://docs.pyrogram.org/start/auth)):

```
from pyrogram import Client

api_id = 12345
api_hash = "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef"

app = Client("my_account", api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash)

app.run()
```

Если токен понятно откуда брать и зачем он нужен, то вот c id и hash возникают затруднения. Откуда их брать я узнал в интернете. А вот зачем они нужны, для чего используются? Если это какие-то артефакты моего телеграм бота, почему они сразу не выдаются с токеном?

Comment: Это не для ботов, а для аккаунтов обычных людей

Comment: https://docs.pyrogram.org/start/auth#bot-authorization почитайте

Comment: gord1402, там написано всего одно предложение: Bot tokens replace the users’ phone numbers only — you still need to configure a Telegram API key with Pyrogram, even when using bots. - из чего я пытаюсь догадаться, что api hash, id - это инструмент аутентификации бота. Но почему тогда в pyTelegramBotApi (https://pypi.org/project/pyTelegramBotAPI/) используется только токен, почему там не нужна эта аутентификация?

Comment: @ArtemLP pyTelegramBotApi использует API для ботов, а pyrogram использует MTProto, который изначально создавался для пользовательских приложений (в частности, для официальных клиентов Telegram)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В контексте `API token` я буду понимать `Telegram Bot API`.

Когда вы создаете бота на платформе `Telegram`, вы получаете уникальный `API token`, который является основным инструментом для взаимодействия с API и управления **ботом**. `API token` предоставляет доступ к различным методам `Telegram Bot API`, таким как отправка сообщений, получение обновлений и управление настройками бота. Обычно он передается в HTTP-запросах или используется в библиотеках и SDK для идентификации бота и обеспечения безопасности при вызове API методов.

`Pyrogram` в свою очередь использует немного другой метод взаимодействия, через  `MTProto API` - это такая штука которая предоставляет возможность разработчикам создавать приложения сторонних разработчиков, которые могут взаимодействовать с Telegram, но он используется не для создания ботов, а для создания клиентских приложений, которые могут работать с Telegram на **уровне пользовательского интерфейса**. `API hash` необходим для подтверждения легитимности вашего приложения и безопасности обмена данных между приложением и серверами Telegram.

Чтобы вы не потерялись, я дам вам ссылку для конфигурации собственного приложения Telegram, там же можно и сформировать `Api_id` и `Api_hash`
https://core.telegram.org/api/obtaining_api_id