# Как получить список непрочитанных сообщений в канале или чате на Pyrogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, pyrogram

Есть телеграм бот на python. Планирую его запускать раз в Н времени. Хочется, чтобы он копировал/пересылал все непрочитанные сообщения, которые накопились за это время. Но не могу найти, как получить именно непрочитанные сообщения (а не всю хистори диалога).

Comment: ну если для пользователя есть момент когда пользователь сообщения читает, то для бота данного момента практически не существует, он обрабатывает любое сообщение, следовательно, нужно сохранить историю как отправная точка прочитанных сообщений, далее, после того как появились новые сообщения, опросить в удобный момент историю и сверить с нашей отправной точкой, разница и будет непрочитанными сообщениями, а после этого проинициализировать данную точку прочитанных сообщений

Comment: Если по-другому не получится, видимо придётся так и делать. Но очень не хотелось бы.
У тг есть счётчик непрочитанных сообщений для чата. Если получить его значение, то можно читать не всю хистори повторно, а только последние X сообщений, ориентируясь на значение счётчика.
Тем более, что pyrogram должен бы уметь с ним работать. По крайней мере там есть функции типа GetUnreadMentions и GetUnreadReactions, что довольно схоже

Comment: Кол-во непрочитанных сообщений формируется относительно ВАШЕГО клиента, а не относительно бота, с другой стороны вы можете закопаться в `MTProro api` для создания собственного клиента с вашими данными

Comment: То есть каждый раз я считываю хистори диалога полностью, сохраняю... в следующий запуск делаю то же самое, отбрасываю совпадающие, оставшиеся вывожу. И сохраняю обновлённую копию хистори для сравнения при следующем запуске. Звучит удручающе, потому как сохранение полной хистори жрёт оч много время. Делать это каждый раз для нескольких чатов - это ужасно.
Нет ли какого-то более оптимального пути?

С MTProto api не дружу. Сильно сложно в освоении?

Comment: Тот же `Pyrogram` можно запустить в двух контекстах, это в контексте работы ботом, которое будет использовать `Telegram bot API`, а так же можно запустить в контексте клиента, где используется `MTProto api`, подробнее писал в [одном из своих старых ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1531645/470029)

Comment: По сути, вы можете собрать собственный клиент, который *по вашему* будет работать с непрочитанными сообщениями